# Tor graphics and media resource repository

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, relays, exit-relays

I'm trying to make a video of the Tor Project for [the Project for Awesome](http://www.projectforawesome.com/about) and I need some graphics explaining the Tor network. Is there a centralized resource of graphics and other explanation tools for describing how Tor works for less-technical folk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tor videos and images can be found [here](https://media.torproject.org/).
[This page](https://www.torproject.org/about/overview.html.en) describes how Tor works.
[This page](https://www.torproject.org/docs/hidden-services.html.en) describes how Tor hidden services work.